# validate url without http:// in symfony

Tags: php, validation, symfony1, symfony-1.4

```
  $this->setValidator('website', new sfValidatorAnd(array(
          $this->validatorSchema['website'],

          new sfValidatorUrl(array(), array(
            'invalid' => 'This is not website',
          )),    
  )));
```

this validate **http://google.com**, but **google.com** no. How can i this edit for validate without **http://** ?

Comment: Why not ask your users to enter proper URLs? Or add some JavaScript to prepent http:// if the URL doesn't contain a protocol. Then they'd even know that it belongs there.

Comment: ThiefMaster, there are plenty of use cases where you don't want to hardcode the url protocol in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid you will need to create your own custom validator:

```
class myCustomValidatorUrl extends sfValidatorRegex
{
  const REGEX_URL_FORMAT = '~^
    ((%s)://)?                                 # protocol
    (
      ([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}             # a domain name
        |                                   #  or
      \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}    # a IP address
    )
    (:[0-9]+)?                              # a port (optional)
    (/?|/\S+)                               # a /, nothing or a / with something
  $~ix';

  protected function configure($options = array(), $messages = array())
  {
    parent::configure($options, $messages);

    $this->addOption('protocols', array('http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps'));
    $this->setOption('pattern', new sfCallable(array($this, 'generateRegex')));
  }

  public function generateRegex()
  {
    return sprintf(self::REGEX_URL_FORMAT, implode('|', $this->getOption('protocols')));
  }
}
```

Here `((%s)://)?` mean that now protocol is optional. 
See [sfValidatorUrl](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/validator/sfValidatorUrl.class.php) for an original pattern (REGEX_URL_FORMAT const).

Answer (score 1):

For validating you could use the native PHP function [filter_var](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with the flag FILTER_VALIDATE_URL.

Answer (score -1):

just set the "required" option to false (by default, it is true).

```
  $this->setValidator('url', 
  new sfValidatorUrl(array('required' => false), array(
  'invalid'  => 'invalid url')));
```

Comment: Sorry, but had to -1. this is avoiding the problem, not solving it. Might as well use sfValidatorPass(); then.